# Probability of Two Different and Specific Dice Rolls (2-12) in 3 chances. EX: a 7 and a 6

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, factorial, dice

Let's say I was rolling two dice (2-12 results) three times.  What is the probability I get two specific results with different probabilities during those three trials?

3 trials where I roll two dice.  I'm looking for how often I'll roll AT LEAST one 6 (5/36 each time) and one 7 (6 out of 36).  I want to be able to any tell any number combination.  I know the likelihood of each event and that this is similar to binomial calculation, but the different probabilities make sites like this inadequate:  http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx

Is there a formula for this?  Something involving factorials?  Crunched it out with a friend and we got 13.888888% which is much bigger than the previously mentioned site's 7.4% for getting two 7s.

Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to get at least a $6$ and a $7$: Either you get a third different result, or you get another $6$, or you get another $7$. There are $6$ different orders for three different numbers, and $3$ different orders for a pair and a singleton, so the total probability is

$$
6\cdot\frac5{36}\cdot\frac6{36}\cdot\left(1-\frac5{36}-\frac6{36}\right)+3\cdot\left(\frac5{36}\right)^2\cdot\frac6{36}+3\cdot\left(\frac6{36}\right)^2\cdot\frac5{36}\\
=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot6\cdot25+3\cdot5^2\cdot6+3\cdot6^2\cdot5}{36^3}\\
=\frac{5490}{36^3}=\frac{305}{2592}\approx11.77\%\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I've written this out at home and its helping a ton thank you!  By the looks of it this gets way more complicated (ways to "get" the desired outcomes) as we increase the number of trials.  Is there a concise enough way for determining the likelihood of such an event (a 6 and a 7) even more trials?  Let's say 6 trials?  9 trials?

Comment: Basically, can I easily increase the number of "trials?"

Comment: @TomWike: Yes, but in that case it becomes more efficient to calculate the probability of the complementary event: that you *don't* get such a pair. This is the probability of not getting a $6$ plus the probability of not getting a $7$ minus the probability of getting neither; in the present case:

$$
1-\left(\frac{31^3}{36^3}+\frac{30^3}{36^3}-\frac{25^3}{36^3}\right)=\frac{5490}{36^3}\;.
$$

Come to think of it, that would actually have been more efficient even in this case :-) But when you have more trials, the difference becomes more pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: First this is an answer to the question "*What is the probability I get two specific results with different probabilities during those three trials?*" as i understood it...)

If i correctly understand the setting, then we have at each step (one of the three steps) the following (sums, possibilities to get the sum,) probability:

- sum is $2$, $(1,1)$, probability $1/36$,
- sum is $3$, $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$, probability $2/36$,
- sum is $4$, $(1,3)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,1)$, probability $3/36$,
- sum is $5$, $(1,4)$, $(2,3)$, $(3,2)$, $(4,1)$, probability $4/36$,
- sum is $6$, $(1,5)$, $(2,4)$, $(3,3)$, $(4,2)$, $(5,1)$, probability $5/36$,
- sum is $7$, $(1,6)$, $(2,5)$, $(3,4)$, $(4,3)$, $(5,2)$, $(6,1)$, probability $6/36$,
- sum is $8$, $(2,6)$, $(3,5)$, $(4,4)$, $(5,3)$, $(5,2)$, probability $5/36$,
- sum is $9$, $(3,6)$, $(4,5)$, $(4,4)$, $(6,3)$, probability $4/36$,
- sum is $10$, $(4,6)$, $(5,5)$, $(6,4)$, probability $3/36$,
- sum is $11$, $(5,6)$, $(6,5)$, probability $2/36$,
- sum is $12$, $(6,6)$, probability $1/36$.

Now we further group events with the same probability:

- sum $2,12$, probability $q_1=2/36$,
- sum $3,11$, probability $q_2=4/36$,
- sum $4,10$, probability $q_3=6/36$,
- sum $5,9$, probability $q_4=8/36$,
- sum $6,8$, probability $q_5=10/36$,
- sum $7$, probability $q_6=6/36$.

Now we can forget about the initial way to generate these probabilities, call these new possible results "boxes".

We start a tree steps experiment based on the "boxes" and ask for getting
**not three times the same box**.

(At least i understood like this the question "*What is the probability I get two specific results with different probabilities during those three trials?*")

The probability is
$$
1-\sum_{1\le j\le 6}q_j^3\ .
$$
This is (computed in [sage](http://www.sagemath.org)):

```
sage: Q = [2/36, 4/36, 6/36, 8/36, 19/36, 6/36]
sage: 1 - sum([ q^3 for q in Q ])
4309/5184
sage: _.n()
0.831211419753086
```

---

Now the second question.

We want at least once the sum $6$, and at least once the sum $7$ in the three trials. The new boxes are $6$, $7$, and anything else, $*$. The probabilities are $p_6=5/36$, $p_7=6/36$, 4p_*=1-p_6-p_7=25/36$.
(In between, there is already an answer to this question, so i will go an other way...)

At the first step we get a $6$, a $7$, or a $*$, so we split into cases.

- $6$ first, then we need a $7$ in two steps, it comes either next, or finally, probability
  $$p_6(p_7+(1-p_7)p_7)=p_6p_7(2-p_7)\ .$$
- $7$ first, then we need a $6$ in two steps, it comes either next, or finally, probability
  $$p_7p_6(2-p_6)\ .$$
- $*$ first, then only $67$ or $76$ in the left trials are matching, probability
  $$(1-p_6-p_7)2p_6p_7\ .$$

Putting all together we get
$$
p_6p_7\Big(\ (2-p_7)+(2-p_6)+2(1-p_6-p_7)\ \Big)
=
3p_6p_7\Big(\ (2-p_6-p_7)\ \Big)
\ .
$$
This is explicitly
$$
\frac{305}{2592}
\approx
\color{red}{0.117669}753086420\dots
\ .
$$

---

**Comment:**

From the first comment to this answer, it seems important to know the following generalization:
Let $n\ge 2$ be integer. Which is the probability $P(n)$ for the event, that in an $n$-step trial there is at least one occurence of the sum $6$ (probability for it in one step being $p_6=5/36$), and at least one of
 the sum $7$ (probability for it in one step being $p_7=6/36$).

(Since in the comment box there is not so much space, i will do it here.)

It is simplest to compute the complementary probability $1-P(n)$. Let $A_6(n)$, resp. $A_7(n)$ be the event that the sum $6$, resp. $7$ does not show in $n$ trials. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
1-P(n)
&=
\text{Probability that either $6$, or $7$ does not appear in $n$ steps}
\\
&=
\text{Probability}(A_6(n)\cup A_7(n))
\\
&=
\text{Probability}(A_6(n))
+
\text{Probability}(A_7(n))
-
\text{Probability}(A_6(n)\cap A_7(n))
\\
&=(1-p_6)^n+(1-p_7)^n-(1-p_6-p_7)^n\ .
\\[3mm]
&\text{So:}
\\
P(n) &=
1-(1-p_6)^n-(1-p_7)^n+(1-p_6-p_7)^n\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!  By the looks of it this gets way more complicated (ways to "get" the desired outcomes) as we increase the number of trials.  Is there a concise enough way for determining the likelihood of such an event (a 6 and a 7) with even more trials?  Let's say 6 trials?  9 trials?  Or does such involve that much more work for every chunk, which there are significantly more of?

Comment: Basically, can I easily increase the number of "trials?"

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want at least one each of the sums $m$ and $n$ with $m\ne n$.  Let's say the respective probabilities of sum $m$ and sum $n$ on a roll of two dice are $p_m$ and $p_n$.

Case 1: Get $m$ twice and $n$ once in some order. Probability is $3p_m^2p_n$.

Case 2: Get $m$ once and $n$ twice in some order. Probability is $3p_mp_n^2$.

Case 3: Get $m$ once and $n$ once and some different value once.  Probability is $6p_mp_n(1-p_m-p_n)$.

Add these up to get your total probability.